# date format with extjs 4.1 issue

Tags: extjs4.1

In my model (Ext.data.Model) i have the following property

```
{
    mapping:'Created',
    name:'Created',
    type: 'date',
    format:'d/m/Y'
},
```

On my form i have the following field

```
                    {
                        xtype:'datefield',
                        name:'Created',
                        fieldLabel:' Date',
                        format:'d/m/Y',
                        width: 350
                    },
```

If i select the following date in the picker "01/04/2012" ( i'm in the UK, 1st April 2012)

I get the following in firebug json post "2012-01-04T00:00:00" ( 4th Jan 2012 )

How can i ensure the correct regions are coming through

Answer (score 2):

In your model you define Ext.data.Field.
Have a look in the API docs, Ext.data.Field has no configuration called `format`, but `dateFormat`.

Try this

```
{
    name:'Created',
    type: 'date',
    dateFormat:'d/m/Y'
},
```

and you just need `mapping`, if your data from the backend has a different name as you want to use in the model.

BTW: since ExtJS 4.1.3 there also are two new config items: `dateReadFormat` and `dateWriteFormat` to define different format for the reader and the writer. But if you define `dateFormat` this will be the same for both.

Comment: FYI for readers: the `dateFormat` property isn't in xtype `datefield` in 4.2 Ext.js

Answer (score 1):

on the form field you need the extra property submitFormat:

```
{
    xtype:'datefield',
    name:'Created',
    fieldLabel:' Date',
    format:'d/m/Y',
    width: 350,
    submitFormat: 'd/m/Y'
}
```